# How to stop sql developer to open a new window when connect?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Every time the sql developer connect to a database it open a new window. Is it configurable? Can we stop it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Yes, you can configure it:

Tools -> Preferences -> Database -> Worksheet -> Open a Worksheet on connect